# iPad Multicolumn Layout Questions

Tags: html, css, ios, ipad, webkit

I successfully achieved mutli-column text inside a UIWebView of an iPad using the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.body {
        direction:rtl;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size:24px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body >
<div class="body">
<img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/958_placeholders/placehold.gif"/>
<p>Long text goes here</p>
<img src="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/958_placeholders/placehold.gif" align="left"/>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But there were two things I could not do:

1. How to make the second  be on **top** of the third column of text, not the end. Please bear in mind that the text is variable so I cannot put the  inline.
2. How to evolve this to a multicolumn and a multirow layout. For example the long text in the  got too long, I want it to span to a second row with the same 3 columns, instead of having one row with text longer than the height of an iPad in landscape. Rephrase: I want to flow one body of text in a **2x3** grid when needed, instead of 1x3.

I'm open for any kind of restructure needed for this.